# function inserting text to file. Matlab

Tags: matlab, text, compiler-errors

I am currently working on the function

```
function[check] = store( filename, persons )

fid = fopen(filename,'w');

if exist('fid')
    check = true;
else
    check = false;
end


for i=1:length(persons)

    sprintf(fid, '%s\n',serialize_person(persons(i)));
end
end
```

Serialize_person returns a <1x(length) char>.
What I want if for the store function to create a .txt file named 'filename' and put serialize_person(persons(i)) on line i in that text file.

However, even though serialize_person runs fine by itself, when I try to run the store function I get the error message

```
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in serialize_person (line 3)
out=sprintf ( '<%s>#%s#<%i>\n' , person.name, serialize_date( person.date_of_birth),
person.phone );

Error in store (line 14)
sprintf(fid, '%s\n',serialize_person(persons(i)));
```

Any educated guesses on what might be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the `person` variable that you're referencing in `serialize_person` is actual a struct? The error suggests it's not.

Comment: I think I've somewhat fixed it now, shoule have been serialize_person(persons{i}) instead of (i) since Im taking in a cell of structs.

Answer (score 0):

```
function[check] = store( filename, persons )

fid = fopen(filename,'w');

if exist('fid')
    check = true;
else
    check = false;
end


for i=1:length(persons)

    sprintf(fid, '%s\n',serialize_person(persons{i}));
end
end
```

It was one of those simple mistakes that got under the radar. Persons is a cell of structs, each wich can be put into serialize_person. So the solution to the problem was simply to change (i) to {i} in the for loop.